# error with adding new list typed column using pyspark.sql.functions.arry

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

i get error when i tried to add new array typed column using the pyspark.sql.functions.arry

```
      column = ['id', 'fname', 'age', 'avg_wh']
        data= [('1', 'user_1', '40', 8.5),
                ('2', 'user_2', '6', 1.5),
                ('3', 'user_3', '4', 5.5),
                ('10', 'user_10', '4', 2.5)]

        from pyspark.sql import functions as F

        df = spark.createDataFrame(data,column)
        df.withColumn("lsitColumn" ,F.array(["1","2","3"]))
        df.show()
```

the Error
    `raise_from(converted)   File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`1`' given input columns: [age, avg_wh, fname, id];; 'Project [id#0, fname#1, age#2, avg_wh#3, array('1, '2, '3) AS lsitColumn#8] +- LogicalRDD [id#0, fname#1, age#2, avg_wh#3], false`

**could you please assist what is the roote cause for this error , i managed to create the column by using UDF but i don't understand why this basic failed**

the UDF

```
       extract = f.udf(lambda x: list(["1","2","3"]), ArrayType(StringType()))
       percentielDF = df.withColumn("lsitColumn", extract("id"))
```

i expected to get new DF with list typed column and i get error

Comment: Try this this 
df3 = df.withColumn("lsitColumn" ,F.array(*map(F.lit, ["1","2","3"])))

Comment: thanks @MaheshGupta , yes it's working but i didn't understand the the map(F.lit, ["1", "2", "3"])  ?

Comment: It is mapping the each element and passing as a literal, you can check the same with the doc (for map function )